# Why does it work to print the 4th element when I've only malloc-ated 3?

Tags: python, malloc, cython

Here's an example:

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython -a

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc

def main():
    cdef int *qux = <int*>malloc(3*sizeof(int))
    qux[0] = 4
    qux[1] = 5
    qux[2] = 6
    qux[3] = 7
    print(qux[0])
    print(qux[3])
```

I was expecting the first print statement to work, but for either `qux[3] = 7` to fail, or `print(qux[3])` to print garbage. However, it correctly prints `7`.

Why is this? Does it not matter how much I `malloc` to `qux`?

Comment: Using Cython exposes you to all the quirks of C, including undefined behavior. Memory access in C via pointers (or array indices, which are equivalent) is not safeguarded.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel OK, so it _happens_ to have printed the correct result here, but there's no guarantee of that? Thanks